# Query cost relative to batch (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-execution-plan

I am testing 2 query's to see which one performs better. When I run them, I set Statistics IO, TIME ON. Each time the result is about 6 seconds for query 1 and about 4 seconds for query 2.

I included the actual execution plan. I would expect here to see cost relative to batch of about 60% for query 1. However, it's exactly 50-50. Could anyone explain why the results are not what I expect? Not sure if the query is needed here, but just to be sure:

```
USE MyDB

SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TableA AS S
  LEFT JOIN TableB AS B ON B.Code = S.Code AND YEAR (DateOne) > 2014
WHERE Active = 1;  

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TableA AS S
  LEFT JOIN TableB AS B ON B.Code = S.Code                               
WHERE Active = 1 
  AND DateOne >= '2015-01-01';
```

Edit: there is a non-clustered index on column `DateOne`.

Comment: to perform a good test you should clear your cache before every execution, since both queries are retrieving data from same table and using same index (my guess)

Comment: @B3S thanks for the suggestion, but that is not what's causing this. Tried it, results are exactly the same.

Comment: Please include the table for each column

Comment: Query cost is just an estimate.  It does not run the actual query.

Comment: Query cost relative to batch, in the actual execution plan, is not actual? That's odd... Good to know though, thanks.